# Getting Warning When Using SizeOf

Tags: c, sizeof

I am getting a warning `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]`

I am writing a very basic program which gives the size of the data type but in the Linux environment I am getting this warning whereas in Visual Studio, the program works without any warning. The source code is as below :-

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

 int a;
 printf("\nThe Size Of Integer A Is = \t%d", sizeof(a));

return 0;
}
```

Answer will be appreciated and also can anyone tell me a proper way of solving such kind of warnings as I am new to this C and it's standard.

Comment: All the answers below are correct, but I'm 99% sure that windows lacks "%zu" (because it intentionally refused to support C99)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof` returns `size_t` type. Use `%zu` specifier to print the value of `sizeof`.

```
printf("\nThe Size Of Integer A Is = \t%zu", sizeof(a));
```

---

#### C11 6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators:

> 5  The value of the result of both operators is **implementation-defined**, and its type (an
> `unsigned integer` type) is `size_t`, defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers).

**NOTE:** As [loreb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1803650/loreb) pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144780/getting-warning-when-using-sizeof/21144798?noredirect=1#comment31823530_21144780) that when you will compile your code in Windows, then most probably you will get the warning like:

```
[Warning] unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
[Warning] too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

Comment: Do you have any resource in mind where I could read more about this? Or could you explain a bit more? :)

Comment: This code worked in the Linux environment yesterday but today when I am trying this in Visual Studio, using the `%zu` format specifier, it is not giving the output as 4 bytes but rather printing `zu` as output. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Keep in mind that MSVC doesn't support C99.

Comment: So doesn't that make the code run only on one environment? Anyway to resolve this? o.O Also is there any way I can contact you directly? :|

Comment: On Windows you can use `%u` specifier. As `size_t` is implementation defined, I think on Windows it is of type `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` return `size_t` and not `int`

Use `%zu` in `printf`

Comment: That other guy was quicker than us :-)

Comment: @manuell lol.. yeah! We also need to be quicker and spot on..at the same time ;)

Answer (score 0):

In  C99 the correct format for a size_t variable is %zu.

Use:

```
printf("\nThe Size Of Integer A Is = \t%zu", sizeof(a));
```