# How do I work around the "unknown conversion type character `z' in format" compiler-specific warning?

Tags: c, printf, mips, cross-compiling, format-specifiers

I'm working on code that is cross-compiled to several target architectures.

I looked at the [handful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382862/how-to-printf-a-size-t-without-warning-in-mingw-w64-gcc-7-1) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144780/getting-warning-when-using-sizeof/21144798#21144798) [hits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54265217/mingw64-w64-attributeformat-and-cinttypes-header) from searching Stack Overflow for "printf size_t unknown conversion type character" warning, however those posts all seem to be related to `minGW`, so those answers, essentially `ifdef`ing against `_WIN32`, do not apply to my instance of essentially the same problem, i.e. `printf` not recognizing "`%zu`" as the format-specifier for `size_t`, but with a `mips` cross compiler.

**Is there an existing compiler flag (for the noted cross-compiler) that enables libc to recognize "%zu" as the format-specifier for `size_t`?**

```
$ cat ./main.c
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  size_t i = 42;
  printf( "%zu\n", i );
  return 0;
}

$ /path/to/mips_fp_le-gcc --version
2.95.3
$ 
$ file /path/to/libc.so.6
/path/to/libc.so.6: ELF 32-bit LSB pie executable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld.so.1, for GNU/Linux 2.2.15, not stripped, too many notes (256)
$ 
$ /path/to/mips_fp_le-gcc -mips2 -O2 -EL -DEL -pipe -Wall -Wa,-non_shared -DCPU=SPARC -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -DPROCESS_AUID -DTAGGING -fPIC -I. -I../../../root/include -I../include -I../../../common/include -I../../..
/root/include  -DDISABLE_CSL_BITE -DDISABLE_DNS_LOOKUP     -DOS=UNIX -DLINUX -DPOSIX_THREADS -D__USE_GNU -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DHANDLE_CSL_DUPLICATES  -DOS=UNIX -DLINUX -DPOSIX_THREADS -D__USE_GNU -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DHANDLE_CSL_DUPLICATES  -DOS=UNIX -DLINUX -DPOSIX_THREADS -D__USE_GNU -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DHANDLE_C
SL_DUPLICATES  -DOS=UNIX -DLINUX -DPOSIX_THREADS -D__USE_GNU -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DHANDLE_CSL_DUPLICATES -o ./main.o -c main.c 
main.c: In function `main':
main.c:6: warning: unknown conversion type character `z' in format
main.c:6: warning: too many arguments for format
```

If the direct answer to the bolded question is "no", what are other possible solutions? Possibilities that come to mind are...

1. `register_printf_function()`
2. Wrap the format-specifier in a target-specific macro (similar to [this `minGW`-specific post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382862/how-to-printf-a-size-t-without-warning-in-mingw-w64-gcc-7-1))

...any other ideas? I'd have a strong preference for solutions not involving target-specific preprocessor code, for which reason the above two are not ideal.

I think (but am not sure) that the cross-compiler version is old; are newer versions *of the noted toolchain* known/guaranteed to have a `libc` that recognize "`%zu`" as the format-specifier to `size_t`?

---

Update: This cross-compiler seems to not recognize `-std=c99`; adding it to the compiler flags generates the error "`cc1: unknown C standard 'c99'`"

Comment: If you're trying to write portable code and all else fails, you could introduce a define in the style that `inttypes.h` uses for the `stdint.h` types: `#define PRIuz "lu"` (or whatever you need to use instead of `"zu"`) and `printf("%" PRIuz "\n", i);`. Of course, that requires changing the code, which I believe you're trying to avoid :(

Comment: gcc 2.95.3 was released in 2001. Yes, it's old. 2.95 was the first version to support c99 though so I'm surprised that option gave an error.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_2.html#SEC6), you need `-fstd=c9x` or `-fstd=gnu9x`, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your gcc does not support `z` as a length modifier.  It's nothing to do with MIPS, which makes no difference at all, but rather that version 2.95.3 lacks support.

Support for a `Z` length modifier was added on Feb 9th 1998, commit by Andreas Schwab "c-common.c (format_char_info): Add new field zlen.".  There was a gcc extension of `Z` as a conversion type specifier (rather than length modifier) for `size_t` before that.  This code is in gcc 2.95.3, so it should recognize `Z`, but not `z`.

Support for `z` was added on July 17 2000 by Joseph Myers, "c-common.c (scan_char_table): Allow "z" length modifiers on diouxXn formats".  Despite predating gcc 2.95.3 in time, this was in a gcc 3 branch and wasn't released until until gcc 3.0.  So your ancient compiler simply hasn't got it.

So you could change your code to use `Z`, which is still supported.  You could also define a macro based on compiler version:

```
#if __GNUC__ < 3
#define PZ "Z"
#else
#define PZ "z"
#endif
```

Then use this as in `printf("The size is %"PZ"u\n", sizeof(int));`  You'll still have to modify your code.  But it wouldn't be any different in the end, as the format string, after the preprocessor, would still be `%zu` on newer compilers and `%Zu` on old ones.  The idea of casting the `size_t` arguments to something else will actually change the result of the code, as they will be cast to larger/smaller types in some cases, depending on what `size_t` is and what you cast to.

Alternatively, if you can build your toolchain, you could patch gcc to know about `z`.  I think a one line change in the case statement that uses `zlen` in "c-common.c" would do it.

`register_printf_function()` is part of glibc, which is where the `printf()` code lives.  It would allow you to extend printf with new formats at run time.  There's nothing you could do at compile time with it that will change the compiler.  And I don't believe gcc will be able to know that a new format has been added when it does printf type checking when `register_printf_function()` is used.

Comment: Is it correct for me to say, then, that "%Zu" is backwards compatible (or forward-compatible, depending on your perspective)? I.e. `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { size_t a = 42; printf("%Zu\n"); return 0; }` would be accepted on both the old 2.95.3 compiler as well as newer compilers? Experimentally, the answer appears to be "yes."

Comment: The `Z` length modifier continues to be supported by gcc for warning generation at least up to gcc 9.2.  It's also supported by glibc when the code actually runs.  However, it's not supported by clang for warnings and will generate an "invalid conversion" printf warning.  It will still work at runtime with clang, as glibc is still using the same code for printf.

Answer (score 4):

I work with a big codebase that's compiled under several different compilers, some of which are old and don't understand `%z`, so we just do things like

```
printf("size = %d", (int)size);
```

That's the easy way for small sizes, of course.  If the size might be large, other alternatives are

```
printf("size = %u", (unsigned)size);
```

or

```
printf("size = %lu", (unsigned long)size);
```

(and there are other obvious possibilities as well).

Answer (score 1):

I recently integrated MinGW into our CI process. We had this same warning as well. Except our fix was very simple.

Here was our original code:

```cpp
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
#define FOO(_fmt_argnum, _first_param_num) __attribute__((format (printf, _fmt_argnum, _first_param_num)))
#else
#define FOO(_fmt_num, _first_param_num)
#endif
```

The fix was subtle.

```
#if defined(__clang__)
#define FOO(_fmt_argnum, _first_param_num)  __attribute__((format (printf, _fmt_argnum, _first_param_num)))
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
#define FOO(_fmt_argnum, _first_param_num)  __attribute__((format (gnu_printf, _fmt_argnum, _first_param_num)))
#else
#define FOO(_fmt_num, _first_param_num)
#endif
```

Explanation:

libstdc++ always defines __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO in os_defines.h, so printf functions are always gnu_printf. The non-GNU printf format attribute denotes the legacy MSVCRT which still has no C99 support other than the ll specifier, and expects the MS long double format (same as double). The necessity of the dedicated check for Clang is because Clang doesn't support gnu_printf.

TLDR:

Use `gnu_printf` instead of `printf` when using `GCC`

NOTE: The ordering of the checks matters since `clang` will define `__GNUC__`